# Javascript Importing Modules And Using Them in HTML Document

Tags: javascript, html, server, es6-modules, javascript-import

The problem I have been having is that I cannot get imported modules to work together in vanilla Javascript. Here's my project structure:

```
> toplevel
> index.html
> main.css
> main.js
> js/
> > setup_event_listeners.js
```

main.js:

```
// only import statement
import { setupEventListenersForIndex } from "./js/setup_event_listeners";

...
```

setup_event_listeners.js:

```
// only export
export function setupEventListenersForIndex() {
    addEventListenerToLambdaButton();
    addEventListenerToSubmitButton();
}

...
```

index.html

```
<body>
    ...
    <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
```

I use the Live Server VSCode Extension to host my test server. I have left the default settings as is and have not configured the settings.

When I run the Live Server, the console logs this error:

```
main.js:2
GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/setup_event_listeners net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I have attempted to move the script tag around.
The CSS is loading perfectly fine so I am unsure of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `.js` extension to your import:

```js
import { setupEventListenersForIndex } from "./js/setup_event_listeners.js";
```

As stated in the [Node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#mandatory-file-extensions):

> A file extension must be provided when using the import keyword to resolve relative or absolute specifiers. Directory indexes (e.g. './startup/index.js') must also be fully specified. This behavior matches how import behaves in browser environments, assuming a typically configured server.